# Postgresql get next X rows for each result

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following data:

| sale_id | sale_date | installments | total_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023/01/01 | 2 | 100.0 |
| 1 | 2023/02/01 | 2 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2023/03/01 | 2 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2023/04/01 | 3 | 90.0 |
| 1 | 2023/05/01 | 3 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2023/06/01 | 3 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2023/01/01 | 1 | 100.0 |

I need to divide the total_value of a sale_id by the next X installments. Example: In this scenario, the first row should be 50.00 and the second row also 50.00, as following:

| sale_id | sale_date | installments | total_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023/01/01 | 2 | 50.0 |
| 1 | 2023/02/01 | 2 | 50.0 |
| 1 | 2023/03/01 | 2 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2023/04/01 | 3 | 30.0 |
| 1 | 2023/05/01 | 3 | 30.0 |
| 1 | 2023/06/01 | 3 | 30.0 |
| 2 | 2023/01/01 | 1 | 100.0 |

My first idea was to get everything that total_vale > 0 and for each row get the next X rows based on the installments column, but I can't find a way to get it with single SQL query.

Maybe I'm missing something simple, but someone could help me with ideas? I've tried also to do that via Function in PLpgsql, but I didn't have a good performance with this approach.

I can't just update everything once, since the customer needs to keep this original layout of data.

Comment: It would be nice to share what you tried. At first glance, I would say `ROW_NUMBER() OVER w`/`FIRST_VALUE(total_value) OVER w` with `WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY sale_id ORDER BY sale_date)`, then compare with the value in `installments` should do most of the trick but it looks so obvious I would find strange if you had not already tried it ... and rejected it for a reason you are not sharing.

Comment: @Atmo I changed some details in original question. It's possible the same `sale_id` to have a new payment that needs to divide again for next X rows. 
I hope I'm being clear, and sometimes even an obvious approach would be great! 

I think that using `window` function would not work because I could have another value for the same `sale_id`.

I've tried to solve it via application and Plsql, getting all the rows with `total_value >0` and looping each row using the limit with the `installment` value to get the next rows, the performance was not good since it execute one query for each row.

Answer (score 2):

Create new group whenever new non zero installment appears, then use this groups for further analysis:

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Tk5shV06)

```
with grps as (
  select sale_id, sale_date, installments, total_value,
         sum(case when total_value <> 0 then 1 end) over (partition by sale_id 
                                                          order by sale_date) grp
  from data)
select sale_id, sale_date, installments, total_value, grp,
       case when row_number() over (partition by sale_id, grp order by sale_date) 
              <= installments
            then max(total_value) over (partition by sale_id, grp) / installments 
            else 0
       end val
from grps
```

Answer (score 1):

As Atmo suggested. `installments-row_number()` with the `max(total_value)` per sale_id and `installments` should divide it correctly.

```
select  sale_id
       ,sale_date
       ,installments
       ,case when installments-row_number() over(partition by sale_id, flg order by sale_date) >= 0 then max(total_value) over(partition by sale_id, flg)/installments else 0 end as total_value     
from 
(
select  *
       ,count (case when total_value > 0 then 1 end) over(partition by sale_id order by sale_date) as flg 
from    t
) t
```

| sale_id | sale_date | installments | total_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 50 |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 50 |
| 1 | 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 30 |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 30 |
| 1 | 2023-06-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 30 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 100 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ahZRmPei)

Comment: Good try but that's not going to work with the latest details on the question...

Comment: he changed it after I posted. I'll fix it.

Comment: I don't think that is good. It appears to work based on the fact `installments` has different values for both sales under `sale_id` = 1

Comment: Hi @DannySlor Thanks! But I think it would not work yet, the number of `installment` could be the same if I have a new sale with the same quantity of installments.
I know this model is weird, but it's something about signatures and recurrences of the customers. I've created a Fiddle to show a example with more details.
[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/C8x3tdMW)

Answer (score 0):

There exists a different approach from the other answers (and my original idea in comments) that needs no window function. It uses `generate_series`.

**As a bonus**, it supports installment periods overlapping (but it works just fine if there aren't any) and will generate rows if the existing ones are not enough to store all installments.

On that note, considering the records with `total_value = 0` are basically unnecessary with this method, you could consider removing them, making the table lighter and faster (in case of a `FULL SCAN`) to access. I guess that depends on the constraints you talk about in your question.

Use the below `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT sale_id, sale_date, MAX(installments), SUM(total_value) AS total_value
FROM (
    SELECT sale_id, generate_series(sale_date, sale_date + make_interval(months => installments - 1), interval '1 month')::date, installments, total_value / installments
    FROM MyTable
) T(sale_id, sale_date, installments, total_value)
GROUP BY sale_id, sale_date
ORDER BY sale_id, sale_date
```

I was forced to do something strange with the `installments` column and maybe having the additional records is not what you want.
To "restore" the behavior of the original table on this points, do a `JOIN` (`INNER JOIN` restores `installments` and removes the additional records, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` only restores `installments`):

```
SELECT T.sale_id, T.sale_date, MyTable.installments, SUM(T.total_value) AS total_value
FROM (
    SELECT sale_id, generate_series(sale_date, sale_date + make_interval(months => installments - 1), interval '1 month')::date, installments, total_value / installments
    FROM MyTable
) T(sale_id, sale_date, installments, total_value)
JOIN MyTable ON MyTable.sale_id = T.sale_id AND MyTable.sale_date = T.sale_date
GROUP BY T.sale_id, T.sale_date, MyTable.installments
ORDER BY T.sale_id, T.sale_date
```

You can use either of them to create a view.
However, if your target is to update the table, you do not have to care about the `installments` column (it will not be updated) nor the additional records (an `UPDATE` does not create records), so the `UPDATE` query is:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET total_value = T2.total_value
FROM (
    SELECT sale_id, sale_date, SUM(total_value) AS total_value
    FROM (
        SELECT sale_id, generate_series(sale_date, sale_date + make_interval(months => installments - 1), interval '1 month')::date, installments, total_value / installments
        FROM MyTable
    ) T1(sale_id, sale_date, installments, total_value)
    GROUP BY sale_id, sale_date
) T2
WHERE MyTable.sale_id = T2.sale_id AND MyTable.sale_date = T2.sale_date
```

Just be careful with it (i.e. start a transaction that you can rollback) as this query cannot be repeated if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Data will be divided using the `cte` into groups based on the sale_id and the number of `installments`, and each group will be given a different number using the `row_number` function. Additionally, we will get the maximum `total_value` for each group.

Then the total_value per group will be `max_total_value/installments` where the `row_number` <= `installments`

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
         row_number() over (partition by sale_id, installments order by sale_id, sale_date) as rn,
         row_number() over (order by sale_id, sale_date) - row_number() over (partition by sale_id, installments order by sale_id, sale_date) as grp,
         max(total_value) over (partition by sale_id, installments) as max_total_value
  from mytable
)
select sale_id, sale_date, installments,
       max(case when rn <= installments 
                then max_total_value/installments 
                else 0 end
          ) over (partition by grp, rn) as t_value
from cte c1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6Us9sfON)

After reading the comments and getting some remarks from @Atmo I conclude that there its could be the taken :

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
         sum(case when total_value <> 0 then 1 end) over (partition by sale_id order by sale_date) as grp
  from mytable
),
cte2 as (
  select *, max(total_value) over (partition by grp, sale_id) as max_total_value,
            row_number() over (partition by grp, sale_id order by sale_date) as rn
  from cte
)
select sale_id, sale_date, installments,
       max(case when rn <= installments 
                then max_total_value/installments 
                else 0 end
          ) over (partition by grp, rn, sale_id) as t_value
from cte2
order by sale_id, sale_date
```

First `CTE` will create new group whenever new non zero installment appears.

Second `CTE` will get max value and row number by the 0 based group.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/BV-EuCw_)

Comment: If `installments` is 2 for `total_value` = 90, then this query returns 0 instead of 45.

Comment: Its 45 have a look https://dbfiddle.uk/rL5I3NU5 ? Can you share what exactly you did ?

Comment: I am talking about the value for 01/04. You seem to have changed `total_value` for 01/01 to 90 instead but that is not what I meant. Keep your original Fibble (with 100 for 01/01), change your `INSERT` command so that, for `sale_id=1`, `installments` equals 2 on all records. This causes 2 `PARTITION BY sale_id, installments` to merge together, which is incorrect. @PonderStibbons, in his/her answer, has taken a gap-and-island approach to build partitions: they are built based on finding non-zero values in `total_value`.

Comment: I made an edit can you have a look @Atmo